# Problems with static compilation with gethostbyname method

Tags: c, static, compilation, gethostbyname

When in my code i use gethostbyname for resolve hostname in a socket program and in the compilation i use -static, like this example

```
 gcc -o example -static -ggdb -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack example.c
```

The compilation return me this warning

```
Warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

and when I execute it, the program return me "gethostbyname failed". How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: If you would have google'd the warning you would have found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15165424/1971013).  It's the top search result!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile a static binary which code there a function gethostbyname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165306/compile-a-static-binary-which-code-there-a-function-gethostbyname)