# C++ exceptions are not caught, if app built with "-dynamic -lc -ldl -lpthread"

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, exception

I have C++ app that uses Boost.Asio and OpenSSL.
I try to build app in Ubuntu 16.04 and I am stucked.

All `.cpp` files compiled correctly. Compilation flags: `-m64 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -MMD -std=c++11`

With linking I have a problem. My command line for the linker:

```
LIBS = -static -L$(BOOST_LIBS) -l:..boostlibs \
    -L$(OPENSSL_LIBS) -l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a \
    -Wl,-Bdynamic -lc -ldl -lpthread \
    -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
g++ *.o $(LIBS) -o executablefile
```

(`*.o` means list of all object files needed for the app)

This command works fine, app can be launched. But in this app blocks `try{} catch(...){}` do not work at all. If any exception is thrown - my app terminated.

I made simple app and used only shared libs to build it. I.e. I removed `-Wl,-Bdynamic` from the linker options. All works fine, exceptions catched.
But my app requires shared libs and I do not know what to do with that.

How to fix catching of exceptions?

**P.S.**

Arguments `-Wl,-Bdynamic -lc -ldl -lpthread` needed because without them I get error from the linker:

> /home/.../openssl/openssl-1.0.2h-x64-build/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):
>   In function `dlfcn_globallookup': dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x11): warning:
>   Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime
>   the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /home/.../xxx.o: In
>   function`
>   boost::asio::detail::resolver_service::resolve(std::shared_ptr&,
>   boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_query const&,
>   boost::system::error_code&)':
>   xxx.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail16resolver_serviceINS0_2ip3tcpEE7resolveERSt10shared_ptrIvERKNS3_20basic_resolver_queryIS4_EERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail16resolver_serviceINS0_2ip3tcpEE7resolveERSt10shared_ptrIvERKNS3_20basic_resolver_queryIS4_EERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0xd7):
>   warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications
>   requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used
>   for linking

This error perfectly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165424/1802974) and seems that I have to use shared libraries.

Argument `-Wl,-dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` needed because `g++` not able to locate path to the shared lib `ld`. And if I try to launch compiled app I got error: `No such file or directory`.

**P.S. 2**

I use Ubuntu 16.04.2 and gcc 5.4.0

**UPD**

Just to be clear.
If I add code below to the start of the `main` function - my app terminated.

```
try
{
    throw std::exception();
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cerr << "hello from the catch.";
}
```

Comment: Are you remembering to catch exceptions at/before the exit of each of your thread procs?

Comment: yes. all thread start points wrapped in try-catch. If I add test code into my app with exception thrown from inside the try-catch - app terminated

Comment: Just to be clear the catch(s) are _inside_ the thread procs?

Comment: Yes ) Handling of exceptions is good. The same code on Windows works fine

Comment: Please, look at the update of my question. This is not a C++ problem, this is problem with g++ or some libs

Comment: And have you tried removing `-static`?

Comment: @RustyX Yes, that fixed a problem. I just removed `-static` from the linker options and now everything works fine! Thank you very much!!!