# How to compile C-code on a 64-bit Linux system for an ARM 32-bit executable

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, ubuntu-18.04, gethostbyname

I am using Linux Ubuntu 64-bit and compiling C code to be run in a Linux Armbian 32-bit system. I am using:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c test.c -o test.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o test test.o -static
```

When I test the code on Ubuntu I use gcc/g++, but when I'm finished I compile an link with above  "arm.." and scp "test" to the Armbian 32-system.

This works with simple "Hello World" -code provide the the "-static" is there. If I leave "-static" out even the simple executable won't run on the Armbian 32-system.

But if I include code using, say, "gethostbyname" I'll get get
warning and the resulting executable won't run on the Armbian 32-bit.
What should my compile & link be so that I could compile in Ubuntu 64-bit and copy the executable to the Armbian 32-bit?

The only solution that I've found is do all compile & link on the Armbian, but I want to avoid that since all my tools are not there.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct hostent *lh = gethostbyname("localhost");
if (lh)
    puts(lh->h_name);
else
    herror("gethostbyname");
return 0;
}
```

When linking with:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o test test.o -static -lrt
```

I get a warning:

```
test.c:(.text+0x18): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the libc version used for linking
```

When running it on 32-bit Armbian I get an error:

```
gethostbyname: Resolver internal error
```

When I link with:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o test test.o -lrt
```

I don't get any warning. However when running it on 32-bit Armbian I get an error:

```
unable to execute ./test: No such file or directory
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165306/compile-a-static-binary-which-code-there-a-function-gethostbyname `hat should my compile & link be so that I could compile in Ubuntu 64-bit and copy the executable to the Armbian 32-bit?` So remove `-static`?

Comment: If remove "-static" I get "File not found". The problem (I believe) is that when when linking from Ubuntu "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++" adds dynamic addresses of library functions that are not found in 32-bit Armbian.

Comment: `I'll get get warning: Using 'gethostbyname' ` `get "File not found".` What file? Please post the full verbatim error messages into the question.

Comment: I edited my question and put al messages & source

Answer (score 1):

The "No such file or directory" error when you are trying to run a program that very clearly exists is an evidence of incorrectly set interpreter a.k.a. dynamic linker. On your arm machine, do:

```
 file ./test
 file /bin/ls (or any other dynamically linked executable that works)
```

and compare the outputs.

Use `--dynamic-linker=` option of GNU `ld` to set the correct dynamic linker.

Do *not* try to statically link with `glibc`, it doesn't work (or it doesn't work the way most people expect it to).

Comment: I haven't used ld much.  Is "--dynamic-linker="  available for  g++? What is the the complete linking command in this simple case?
ld ... ?

Comment: Do not use ld directly. gcc can pass any option to ld with `-Wl,`, e.g. `g++ -Wl,--dynamic-linker=...`.

Comment: what comes after "--dynamic-linker="

Comment: the filename of the dynamic linker obviously. What does `file /bin/ls` say?

Comment: I says on the 64-bit: 
"/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9567f9a28e66f4d7ec4baf31cfbf68d0410f0ae6, stripped"

and on the 32-bit:
"/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=4757593a0f8e0a78cab30d64c9022e00af06338c, stripped"

Comment: So you need to set it to `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` because that's what your arm machine needs.

Comment: What would my link command be? I tied "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -WL,dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -o test2 test.o -lrt" but I got "error: unrecognized command line option ‘-WL,dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3’"

Comment: You need `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=...`. I strongly recommend studying command line options of your tools, you will need them.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete link command in addition or for replacing  "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o test test.o -lrt"

Comment: Maybe try `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o test test.o -lrt -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`. I don't have an arm system to check this.